# When calling FtpWebRequest.DownloadFile after FtpWebRequest.UploadFile why am I getting an exception?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have two methods (C# 4.8): one that uploads a file to a server directory using FTP, and one that downloads a file from a server using FTP. Each of these work fine independently. However, when I call the `UploadFile(...)` method followed by the Download method, an exception is thrown on the `FtpWebRequest.Create(...)` method in the `DownloadFile(...)` method.

I can call `DownloadFile(...)` successively without problems.

Am I missing something, perhaps to close the connection?

The exception is:

```
Message:        "The remote server returned an error: 226-File successfully transferred\r\n226 1.707 seconds (measured here), 4.59 Mbytes per second\r\n."

InnerException: null

Status:         ProtocolError
```

My code is:

```
public void UploadFile(FileInfo SourceFile, string Domain, string TargetFileName, string Username, string Password)
{
    FtpWebRequest _FTPRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Domain + TargetFileName);
    _FTPRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    _FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    _FTPRequest.UseBinary = true;
    _FTPRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    _FTPRequest.UsePassive = true;

    using (FileStream fileStream = SourceFile.OpenRead())
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)_FTPRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream ftpStream = _FTPRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int iRead;
        while ((iRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, iRead);
    }
}

public void DownloadFile(ref byte[] TargetArray, string Domain, string SourceFileName, string Username, string Password)
{
    FtpWebRequest _FTPRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Domain + SourceFileName); // exception is thrown here //
    _FTPRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
    _FTPRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    _FTPRequest.UseBinary = true;
    _FTPRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    _FTPRequest.UsePassive = true;

    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)_FTPRequest.GetResponse())
    using (Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int totalRead = 0;
        int iRead;
        while ((iRead = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            if (buffer.Length > iRead) Array.Resize<byte>(ref buffer, iRead);
            Array.Resize<byte>(ref TargetArray, TargetArray.Length + iRead);
            buffer.CopyTo(TargetArray, totalRead);
            totalRead += iRead;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What response are you getting on the upload?  You may be getting an error. so file wasn't written correctly.

Comment: @jdweng No, it doesn't matter what file I'm trying to download, or what method the file was used to upload it to the server. It errors whenever I try to download anything after uploading anything.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for the clue! It took me a really long time to figure out how to enable the logging, but once I did it got me steered in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when I called `_FTPRequest.GetResponse()` before `_FTPRequest.GetRequestStream()`, it actually opened two separate requests and they were conflicting. I'm not yet clear as to why it only affected the subsequent download method, but once I removed that line completely, the methods worked as expected.